# How to setup react properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, terminal, webpack, frontend

I have been following the react setup instructions on codecademy:

When I type in "npm run build" into the terminal I get this error:

[image]

I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work.

Here is the link to my code on my github:
https://github.com/throwkill999/react_demo

Comment: Do you have webpack installed globally?

Comment: I don't have webpack installed globally. The webpack website says it's not recommended, so I'm not sure if I should.

Comment: If you want to use the CLI, you should

Comment: I installed webpack globally and I am still getting the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you that `output.build` is not a valid option. You probably meant to use [`output.path`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-path). There are other problems with how you concatenate `__dirname` in some places, because you need a leading `/` for them. But it's better to use [`path.resolve`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths) for that.

Your config would look like this:

```
var path = require('path');
var HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
    template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/index.html'),
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/index.js'),
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'transformed.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
    },
    plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig]
};
```

Also in `./app/index.js` you have a typo, it should be `./components/Apps` (you forgot the `s`).

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I put in the code you wrote above. I am still getting the exact same errors saying "output.build is not a valid option". I'm not sure what else I can do.

Comment: Make sure to overwrite your `webpack.config.js` with the posted code. You can only get the error if you kept your old config.